# Foreign Key Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, foreign-keys, primary-key

When I try to create this table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE ticket_id_seq;
create table Ticket (
  ticket_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('ticket_id_seq') NOT NULL,
  event_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
  performance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
 seat_area VARCHAR(30),
 order_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY (order_id) REFERENCES Order_info (order_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON             UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (performance_id) REFERENCES Performance (performance_id) ON   DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (ticket_id));
```

I get error: "ERROR:  there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "performance"

But this doesn't make sense to me since the table in referencing Performance, uses performance_id as a primary key:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE performance_id_seq;
create table Performance (
   event_id  INTEGER NOT NULL,
   performance_id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('performance_id_seq') NOT NULL,
   event_status VARCHAR(10),
   performance_date VARCHAR(45),
   performance_time VARCHAR(20),
   venue_id INTEGER,
  nbr_seats INTEGER,
  purchase_limit INTEGER,
  posting_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  sale_start_date DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE,
  minimum_ticket_price VARCHAR(30),
  maximum_ticket_price VARCHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (event_id) REFERENCES Event (event_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY (venue_id) REFERENCES Venue (venue_id) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
PRIMARY KEY (event_id, performance_id));
```

So I'm really not sure why I'm getting this error as performance_id is a unique primary key in its own table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your primary key in `Performance` consists of two columns, the pai4 (`event_id, performance_id`).

I'm not sure what your intent is, but `performance_id` is unique because of the use of the sequence.  So, you can just use:

```
PRIMARY KEY (performance_id);
```

for the `performance` table.  I would also make it the first column, to make it clear that `event_id` is just an attribute of a performance.

If you use multiple columns to define a primary key, then you need to use all the columns when you reference the table using a foreign key.

Answer (score 1):

`performance_id` is not unique on its own. It's just part of primary key; pair `(event_id, performance_id)` is unique. There can be several rows with same `performance_id` (but different `event_id`).